# Running Docker containers as non-root shows they are running as systemd+

Tags: docker, nginx, containers

I am trying to get Nginx and Mosquitto to run as a non-root user. I set the user option and am using the Nginx image and a Ubuntu image with Mosquitto installed in it. When I do a docker top nginx or mosquitto it gives me this output which says it is running as systemd.

> admins@mmig:/folder/docker/folder$ docker top mosquitto
> UID                 PID                 PPID                C                   STIME               TTY                 TIME                CMD
> systemd+            1116290             1116273             0                   16:31               ?                   00:00:00            /bin/sh -c mosquitto -v -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
> systemd+            1116404             1116290             1                   16:31               ?                   00:00:00            mosquitto -v -c /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf

How can I get it to run as the user I am wanting it to run as instead which is mosquitto in this case?

Comment: Does `docker exec mosquitto ps -f` say something different?  Can you include your image's Dockerfile and other necessary source code for a [mcve]?

Comment: Yes running it with the command you included it does say it is running as mosquitto. I wonder why systemd shows from the docker command. I am guessing since "docker top mosquitto" is getting the information from my local /etc/passwd file that is why it is showing as systemd-resolve as that is the same UID as my mosquitto user in the container. I will just change the UID of the mosquitto user.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

When using "docker top mosquitto" I was seeing the UID of my local host /etc/passwd file and not the UID in the /etc/passwd file in the container. To fix this I will have to change the UID on the mosquitto user in the container.